# How can I propagate an element is invalid after executing jqueryvalidation?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-validate

When pressing a form's submit-button the form validation is executed. A specific element - a dropdown list - might fail the validation and receive a new class marking it as invalid. When this class is added I would like to have another separate DOM element to be notified about this new class added. The other element must then copy the error class from the validated element to its own class attribute for styling (vice versa when re-validation succeeded). This behavior does not apply to all form elements. So a general implementation via the plugin's highlight- or errorPlacement-callbacks appears to be unusable in my case, because from what i understood this callback applies to all form elements rather than a single form element which is what i need.

I seem to stuck with how to hook into the validation process via a listener. I checked the [Plugin Docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) to figure out whether and where there might be an event triggered after validation but cannot find any information regarding.

Did somebody of you probably have the same requirement and found a working solution you might share?

**EDIT:**
Problem description was extended to clarify the problem

Comment: Really?  [The page you've linked to](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) shows callback functions that fire during validation of an individual element, such as `errorPlacement` and `highlight`.  So where is your code?

Comment: Yes, really! I am not talking about highlighting the validated element or change the error position. Ofcourse I noticed these callback functions. But they do not know about any other DOM elements listening! I need another independent element to get notified when the element to be validated has finished its validation. The other element must then execute code. So note, i am talking about TWO independent and separate elements. So please correct your down vote! I did research enough! But obviously I stuck with the understanding, which is not a research issue!

Comment: You have failed to adequately explain what you're trying to do.  What exactly is this other element listening for?  The only "events" are like `click`, `keyup`, or `blur` and you never mentioned anything about these.  There is no such thing as a `validate` event.  However, I cannot formulate a "workaround" when I have no idea what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ofcourse there is. It is triggered as soon as you click the submit button and validates all form elements. This process adds a new class 'invalid' or 'valid'. Setting/Removing this extra class attribute is when the other element must be notified about that. Of course i am able to bind to focus/blur, but this is not triggerend when pressing the submit-button!

Comment: *"It is triggered as soon as you click the submit button"*.  ~  That is not a `validate` "event"... that is a `click` event and the element styling is **controlled by the `highlight` option** from within the plugin.  Carefully read my answer below.

Comment: I extended my initial post to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: *"I seem to stuck with how to hook into the validation process via a listener."* ~  There is no `event` or `listener` for the validation process.  The built in events are `focusout`, `keyup`, and `click`.  Otherwise, you can write a custom event handler (using a standard jQuery/JavaScript) event and trigger the validation itself using the `.valid()` method.

Comment: *"from what i understood this callback is not applyable to a single form element."* ~ not true, you can use a conditional.  "If this matches element, then do that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The other element must receive the validated elements error-class for styling.

You would use the `highlight` option to apply styling as needed.  When using the `highlight` option, you would also use the `unhighlight` option to do the opposite.

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    // and/or something like this?
    $(element).parent('div').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
    // and/or something like this?
    $(element).parent('div').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

The above is a very generic example that is similar to the default.  You would need to do something of your own using any appropriate jQuery DOM traversal methods.  You never really described exactly what you were trying to do, so there is no way I can provide a custom solution.

---

**EDIT**

You can *conditionally* apply these functions so that it only affects a certain element(s).

In this example the error/valid classes will *also* be applied to the sibling `select` elements of any input element with the class `.foo`.  You can edit the conditional and the jQuery selector as needed...

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); // default
    // with something like this?
    if ($(element).hasClass('foo')) {
        $(element).siblings('select').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    }
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass); // default
    // with something like this?
    if ($(element).hasClass('foo')) {
        $(element).siblings('select').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
    }
}
```